# Define POST in coreapi/django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, core-api

Is there a way to define the object for a post function in the schema of django rest framework?

I have a rest api view:

```
class DocumentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    queryset = Document.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    serializer_class = serializers.DocumentSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultPagination
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_class = (
        Token,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

The data that should be posted is of format:

```
{
     "items": ["a", "b", "c"],
     "name": "test" 
}
```

How can I describe that in the schema using coreapi?

```
manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field(
            "data",
            required=True,
            location="body",
            description='{"items":[], "name":str}',
            schema=coreschema.Object()
        ),
    ])
```

So at least it will be in the description. This of course is not very convinient, especially igf you need more fields in the to-be-posted JSON, since the description is single-line only in swagger.

The most ideal situation would be if I could get the 'items' and the 'name' field as separate fields in the swagger page.

I've googled, but I cannot find an answer for this. Al the examples I saw are for get parameters. So what is best practice here?

Comment: Is there a way to have this JSON as the Example value for the body in the POST API?

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you wrap it to AutoSchema

```
schema = AutoSchema(manual_fields=[
    coreapi.Field(
        "data",
        required=True,
        location="body",
        description='{"items":[], "name":str}',
        schema=coreschema.Object()
    ),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

it is been a long time from this question but if someone needs, this is your solution, you need to set location to 'form', so your schema would be like this one:

```
manual_fields=[
    coreapi.Field(
        "data",
        required=True,
        location="form",
        description='{"items":[], "name":str}',
        schema=coreschema.Object()
    ),
])
```

For more instructions you can see [Schemas - Django Rest Framework](https://django-rest-framework-old-docs.readthedocs.io/en/3.8.2/api-guide/schemas/#api-reference)

Here I extract the section you need:

> LOCATION
>
> Determines how the information is encoded into the request. Should be
> one of the following strings:
>
> "path"
>
> Included in a templated URI. For example a url value of
> /products/{product_code}/ could be used together with a "path" field,
> to handle API inputs in a URL path such as /products/slim-fit-jeans/.
>
> These fields will normally correspond with named arguments in the
> project URL conf.
>
> "query"
>
> Included as a URL query parameter. For example ?search=sale. Typically
> for GET requests.
>
> These fields will normally correspond with pagination and filtering
> controls on a view.
>
> "form"
>
> Included in the request body, as a single item of a JSON object or
> HTML form. For example {"colour": "blue", ...}. Typically for POST,
> PUT and PATCH requests. Multiple "form" fields may be included on a
> single link.
>
> These fields will normally correspond with serializer fields on a
> view.
>
> "body"
>
> Included as the complete request body. Typically for POST, PUT and
> PATCH requests. No more than one "body" field may exist on a link. May
> not be used together with "form" fields.
>
> These fields will normally correspond with views that use
> ListSerializer to validate the request input, or with file upload
> views.